# Compile error: Argument not optional when calling sub

Tags: vba, excel, arguments

So, while I have read some of the many questions on here about similar errors, I haven't found one which helped me understand my problem, so far. If their is a similar question with an appropriate answer, please link it and I shall remove this one.

Now, I am using a small sub `Refresh_Activesheet()` to look at the name of the WorkSheets and according to that name run the appropriate sub. Most of the subs are in the same module as `Refresh_Activesheet()`. However, two are in their separate module, for the moment. Now the problem is that when I run `Refresh_Activesheet` vba returns the argument not optional error and I can't fathom why.

`Refresh_Activesheet`

```
Sub Refresh_Activesheet()

    If IsNumeric(Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 1)) Then
        Emissions_Calculation
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Voyages List" Then
        Refresh_Table
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Émission Total" Then
        Call Refresh_Emissions.Emission_Total
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Consommation Total" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

`Refresh_Emissions` which is the module that contains `Emission_Total`

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public j, i, k, n, m, p, l, info, mation, Total As Variant
Public AverageEmission, TotalEmission As String

Sub Emission_Total(ByVal ws As Worksheet)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

Dim SoxRevenue, SoxGross, MilesTotal, MilesLaden, CargoMT As Double

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("A7 : M200").Clear
j = 7
k = 1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If IsNumeric(Left(ws.Name, 1)) Then
        ws.Unprotect ("12345")

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission Total").Range("A" & j).Value = ws.Range("C5").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission Total").Range("B" & j).Value = ws.Range("T2").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission Total").Range("C" & j).Value = ws.Range("T3").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission Total").Range("D" & j).Value = ws.Range("G2").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission Total").Range("E" & j).Value = ws.Range("J2").Value

        info = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F7 : M200").Address
        mation = ws.Range("D6:D8").Address

        SoxRevenue = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("V28:V30").Value)
        SoxGross = ws.Range("V43").Value
        MilesLaden = ws.Range("M4").Value
        MilesTotal = ws.Range("M6").Value
        CargoMT = ws.Range("O5").Value

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range(info)
            If (ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) = "" Then
             .Cells(k, 1).Value = ws.Range("W49").Value
             .Cells(k, 2).Value = ws.Range("W50").Value
             .Cells(k, 3).Value = ws.Range("W54").Value
             .Cells(k, 4).Value = ws.Range("W56").Value
             .Cells(k, 5).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 6).Value = SoxRevenue
             .Cells(k, 7).Value = SoxGross * 1.852 * 1000 * 1000 / (CargoMT * MilesTotal)
             .Cells(k, 8).Value = SoxRevenue * 1.852 * 1000 * 1000 / (CargoMT * MilesLaden)

             .Cells(k, 1).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 2).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 3).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 4).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 5).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 6).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 7).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 8).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

            ElseIf (ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) = 0 Then
             .Cells(k, 1).Value = ws.Range("W49").Value
             .Cells(k, 2).Value = ws.Range("W50").Value
             .Cells(k, 3).Value = 0
             .Cells(k, 4).Value = 0
             .Cells(k, 5).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 6).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 7).Value = 0
             .Cells(k, 8).Value = 0

             .Cells(k, 1).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 2).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 3).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 4).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 5).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 6).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 7).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 8).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

             ElseIf (ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) = 0 And (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value) = 0 Then
             .Cells(k, 1).Value = ws.Range("W49").Value
             .Cells(k, 2).Value = ws.Range("W50").Value
             .Cells(k, 3).Value = (ws.Range("W49").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) + (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 4).Value = 0
             .Cells(k, 5).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 6).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 7).Value = (ws.Range("V43").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) + (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 8).Value = 0

             .Cells(k, 1).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 2).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 3).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 4).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 5).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 6).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 7).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 8).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

             ElseIf (ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) = "" And (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value) = "" Then
             .Cells(k, 1).Value = ws.Range("W49").Value
             .Cells(k, 2).Value = ws.Range("W50").Value
             .Cells(k, 3).Value = (ws.Range("W49").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) + (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 4).Value = 0
             .Cells(k, 5).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 6).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 7).Value = (ws.Range("V43").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) + (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 8).Value = 0

             .Cells(k, 1).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 2).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 3).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 4).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 5).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 6).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 7).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 8).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

            Else
             .Cells(k, 1).Value = ws.Range("W49").Value
             .Cells(k, 2).Value = ws.Range("W50").Value
             .Cells(k, 3).Value = (ws.Range("W49").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) + (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 4).Value = (ws.Range("W50").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 5).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 6).Value = ws.Range("V43").Value
             .Cells(k, 7).Value = (ws.Range("V43").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value) + (ws.Range(mation).Cells(3, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853
             .Cells(k, 8).Value = (ws.Range("V43").Value) / ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(1, 1).Value) * ((ws.Range(mation).Cells(2, 1).Value))) * 1000 * 1000 / 1.853

             .Cells(k, 1).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 2).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 3).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 4).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
             .Cells(k, 5).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 6).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 7).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
             .Cells(k, 8).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

            End If

         End With

        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1

        ws.Protect ("12345")

    ElseIf ws.Name = "Émission total" Then
        ws.Unprotect ("12345")

    End If

Next ws
    k = k + 7
    p = k - 1

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("D" & k).Value = "AverageEmission"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F7 : F" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("G" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("G7 : G" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("H" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("H7 : H" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("I" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("I7 : I" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("J" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("J7 : J" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("K" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("K7 : K" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("L" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("L7 : L" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("M" & k).Value = Application.Average(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("M7 : M" & p))

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("G" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("H" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("I" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("J" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("K" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("L" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("M" & k).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

    l = k + 2

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("D" & l).Value = "TotalEmission"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F7 : F" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("G" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("G7 : G" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("H" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("H7 : H" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("I" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("I7 : I" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("J" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("J7 : J" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("K" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("K7 : K" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("L" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("L7 : L" & p))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("M" & l).Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("M7 : M" & p))

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("F" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("G" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("H" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("I" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.00"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("J" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("K" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("L" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission total").Range("M" & l).NumberFormat = "?0.0000"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Émission Total").Protect ("12345")
ThisWorkbook.Protect ("12345")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error?

Comment: The first `Refresh_Activesheet`, as far as I can discern. `Refresh_Emissions` works fine on its own. The error is thrown at the `Call`.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break-point in that procedure then stepping through (F8) to make sure? Refresh_ActiveSheet itself takes no arguments, so it must be something else.

Comment: You should remove (or at least comment out) On Error Resume Next (5th line of code in that long code block). That's blocking errors from displaying and you need that information. That's something you should never set except for a very specific reason.

Comment: I mention, also, that you need to specify the data type for every variable declaration. Using "As String" (or whatever) at the end of a comma-separated list of variables only works on the last variable. All the rest will be of type Variant.

Comment: Well that solves one problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
Call Refresh_Emissions.Emission_Total
```

In that line, you don't provide an argument.  But the `Emission_Total` subroutine *requires* that a worksheet object be provided as an argument, as shown by its declaration:

```
Sub Emission_Total(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
```

It looks like you are calling different subroutines based on the worksheet name, so my guess is you simply want to send the worksheet that matched the call, in which case:

```
Sub Refresh_Activesheet()

    If IsNumeric(Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 1)) Then
        Emissions_Calculation
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Voyages List" Then
        Refresh_Table
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Émission Total" Then
        Call Refresh_Emissions.Emission_Total(ActiveSheet)  'Note I added the worksheet as an argument here
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Consommation Total" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Looking at your posted code some more, it looks like you never actually use the passed worksheet variable in the `Emission_Total` subroutine.  In which case you could just remove the ws variable requirement from the declaration:

```
Sub Emission_Total()
```

And then leave your `Refresh_Activesheet` code as you originally posted.

Comment: Thanks mate, did the trick. Reworking code made by better and more advanced programmers than oneself can be rather confusing, at least for me.